# Magento module access denied for user with custom role

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin

I have a module 'BlogMate' which is only accesible for users that have access to everything. Even when I change the role so the user can't access a completely unrelated part, the module gives an access denied page.

Why is that?

I don't want to give users 100% access just so they can acccess this module.

Maybe the following XML is relevant, I've seen similair questions post it.

path: app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magik_BlogMate>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magik_BlogMate>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <blogmate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magik_BlogMate</module>
                    <frontName>blog</frontName>
                </args>
            </blogmate>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <blogmate>
                    <file>blogmate.xml</file>
                </blogmate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <blogmate>
                <class>Magik_BlogMate_Helper</class>
            </blogmate>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <blogmate>
                <class>Magik_BlogMate_Block</class>
            </blogmate>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <blogmate>
                <class>Magik_BlogMate_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>blogmate_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </blogmate>
            <blogmate_mysql4>
                <class>Magik_BlogMate_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <blog>
                        <table>magik_blog</table>
                    </blog>       
                    <category>
                        <table>magik_blog_category</table>
                    </category>       
                    <comment>
                        <table>magik_blog_comment</table>
                    </comment>
                </entities>
            </blogmate_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <blogmate_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Magik_BlogMate</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </blogmate_setup>
            <blogmate_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </blogmate_write>
            <blogmate_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </blogmate_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                                <args>
                                        <modules>
                                                <blogmate before="Mage_Adminhtml">Magik_BlogMate_Adminhtml</blogmate>
                                        </modules>
                                </args>
                        </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <blogmate module="blogmate">
                <title>BlogMate</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <blogmatebackend module="blogmate">
                        <title>Blog Settings</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/blogmate</action>
                    </blogmatebackend>
                    <blog module="blogmate">
                        <title>Manage Blog</title>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/blogmate_blog</action>
                    </blog>
                    <category module="blogmate">
                        <title>Manage Category</title>
                        <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/blogmate_category</action>
                    </category>
                    <comment module="blogmate">
                        <title>Manage Comment</title>
                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/blogmate_comment</action>
                    </comment>
                </children>
            </blogmate>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <blogmate translate="title" module="blogmate">
                            <title>BlogMate</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <blogmatebackend translate="title">
                                    <title>Blog Settings</title>
                                </blogmatebackend>
                                <blog translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Blog</title>
                                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                                </blog>
                                <category translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Category</title>
                                    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                                </category>
                                <comment translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Comment</title>
                                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                </comment>
                            </children>
                        </blogmate>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <blogmate>
                    <file>blogmate.xml</file>
                </blogmate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: add this code in admin controllers and try once : `protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}`

Answer (score 4):

Add this function in controller file.

```
/**
     * Check for is allowed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
     protected function _isAllowed() {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: welcome to Stackexchange @sumilsanghavi

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: @Sumil sanghavi there are multiple controllers, what controller file do I need?

Comment: Every separate controller has define separate RESOURCE IDENTIFIER in the ACL

Example : For this controller 

<blogmatebackend translate="title">
    <title>Blog Settings</title>
</blogmatebackend>

ADD this below funciton in the contoller file of the aobve code

/**
     * Check for is allowed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
     protected function _isAllowed() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/blogmatebackend'); 
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('Children KEY/RESOURCE IDENTIFIER');
    }

Comment: @Sumilsanghavi So it is app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/controllers/Adminhtml/Blogmate/BlogMatebackendController.php ?

Comment: Yes. It is only for the above first acl code.

Comment: @Sumilsanghavi What does acl mean?

Comment: @twan Access Control List

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just modify the .php files inside the controllers folder in your module. Add it within the class that you extended. It can be the first or the last function, as long as it's added, it will fix the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with this exact module. Hopefully this full breakdown helps save anyone else some time.

**Please Note**: Some other answers in this thread are correct but more generic, I am expanding on these with a full breakdown for this specific Magento Extension.

## **Understanding The Problem**

After creating a custom User Role in **System>Permissions>Roles** with permission to view only the BlogMate section of the admin as the image shows below:

[image]

Any Users assigned this Role will see the following Access Denied message when they try access any of the sections in the Admin (even though the links show in the admin menu):

[image]

## **Solution**

As other answers point out you must add to following code to the module controllers:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}
```

**Here is a full breakdown of the exact code needed:**

Add the following code to app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/controllers/ Adminhtml/BlogmatebackendController.php:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/blogmatebackend');
}
```

Add the following code to app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/controllers/ Adminhtml/BlogController.php:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/blog');
}
```

Add the following code to app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/controllers/ Adminhtml/CategoryController.php:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/category');
}
```

Add the following code to app/code/community/Magik/BlogMate/controllers/ Adminhtml/CommentController.php:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/comment');
}
```

I added these functions just below the opening of the class, e.g:

```
class Magik_BlogMate_Adminhtml_CommentController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('blogmate/comment');
    }
...
```

**Lastly**, if you are still having trouble providing access to the BlogMate Blog Settings, this is because they are a section within **System>Config**, so make sure you add this permission to your role!

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code in admin controller :

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you create the module access for all user but have some restriction with custom role based user.

Use below code inside controller, it will allow to anyuser have the access.

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
        return true;
}
```